# CSS: When I add a button to my container, my layout breaks, how to avoid this?

Tags: html, css

I've read many things about this, and how to use wrappers to avoid this, I've even gone through some responsive design tutorials, but I can't remember how to fix this, or why this happens, and the tutorials about responsive design are extensive, I haven't been able to find the answer to this.

I'm using pure divs to try and give the style I want, using % for height and width, and it's working fine, but I have encountered this problem, when I add a button to one of my subcontainers, my inline-block breaks, and I don't know why. If anybody cares to explain why it happens and how to avoid this.

Here's the html:

```
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="izquierda">
        <div class="logocont">
            <input type="button"  class="btn1" style="display:block" value="Hide/Show" onclick="hideshow()"/>
        </div>
        <div class="display">

        </div>
        <div class="totalcont">
            Total:                  
        </div>
    </div><div class="derecha">
        <div class="btnsarriba">
            <input type="button"  class="btn1" id="btn1" value="Clientes"/>
        </div>
        <div class="btnsproductos">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
html{
width: 95%;
height: 95%;
}

body {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
}
.contenedor{
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.izquierda{
width:40%;
height:100%;
display: inline-block;
}

.derecha{
width:60%;
height:100%;
display: inline-block;
}

.display {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: #6B6868;  
width:90%;
height:70%;
margin-left: 5%;
background-color: #6B6868;
}

.logocont{
width: 70%;
height: 16%;
background-color: #DCD4D4;
margin: auto;
}

.totalcont{
width:90%;
margin-left: 5%;
background-color: #C4C3C3;
}

.displaytable{
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

.totaltable{
width: 100%;

}

.btnsarriba{
width: 90%;
height: 16%;
margin: auto;
background-color: #DCD4D4;
}

.btnsproductos {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
border-color: #6B6868;
width:90%;
height:70%;
margin-left: 5%;
background-color: #6B6868;
}
```

Here's the JS:

```
function hideshow(){
 var status = document.getElementById('btn1').style.display;
if (status == "block"){
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = "none";
}else{
    document.getElementById('btn1').style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v46ytono/2/

I added the hide/show button just to make it simpler to show, I would like that hiding or showing the button would have no effect on my layout.

**Edit:** To make it clearer, this is my issue:
If you click the hide/show button, which hides and shows the "Clientes" button, my 2 main divs "izquierda" and "derecha" move around, when the "Clientes" button is showing, my right div drops down, when the button hides, it goes up, I would like that not to happen.

Comment: I don't get what's that for a layout, the spaces around it, what's the real issue, how it should look like, what's the mess you're talking about a.s.on

Comment: If you click the hide/show button, which hides and shows the "Clientes" button, my 2 main divs "izquierda" and "derecha" move around, when the "Clientes" button is showing, my right div drop down, when the button hides, it goes up, I would like that not to happen.

Comment: If I correctly understand your question, Try using float for divs. Eg: float:left. It may  help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are `inline-block`, you could change the `vertical-align` property's value to something other than the default, `baseline`. Values such as `top`/`middle`/`bottom` work.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5rhLyxde/)

```
.izquierda, .derecha {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below code in your CSS:

```
#btn1 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v46ytono/3/)

Comment: This worked too, but Josh Crozier answered first, so I marked his answer as the answer, thanks though.